# CDateValidator set null when empty

Tags: php, validation, datetime, yii

I'm going crazy trying out different solutions on the net of a fairly simple problem

I have *literally* hundreds of dates being stored by my application, and my client's source data has a bad habit of dates being in different formats.

For example, one of my models has rules as followed (for completion all are listed for this specific model)

```
    public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('function, junior, ces,agreement_expected,start_date', 'required'),
            array('start_budget', 'numerical'),
            array('visa_received,training_days', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
            array('function, junior, ces,currency', 'length', 'max' => 10),
            array('agreement_received, status, stop_date_original, stop_date_extended', 'safe'),
            array('agreement_received,  visa_received, stop_date_original, stop_date_extended', 'default', 'setOnEmpty' => true, 'value' => null),
            array('agreement_received,agreement_expected,start_date,stop_date_original,stop_date_extended', 'date', 'format' => 'Y-m-d', 'allowEmpty' => true),
            array('id, Sname,PFces, PFdomain,PDkeyword, PFstatus, PRname,PRcountry,PRscore,PRcomment,PRngo,TRname,TRpic, TFfunction, TFx, TRdateofbirth,TRedufields,TRcoach,TRlocation,TRtask,TRcontract,TRproject,TRcontact,TFdateofbirth,TFedufields,TFcoach,TFlocation,TFtask,TFcontract,TFproject,TFcontact, 
date1,date2,idate, ddomains,dkeywords,country,agreement, function,ngo, status,group, junior, junior_lastname, junior_firstname,search_all,search_interrupt, ces, agreement_expected, agreement_received, visa_received, start_date, stop_date_original, stop_date_extended,currency, start_budget, training_days', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
        );
    }
```

what I want to achieve is depicted by following rules

```
        array('agreement_received,  visa_received, stop_date_original, stop_date_extended', 'default', 'setOnEmpty' => true, 'value' => null),
        array('agreement_received,agreement_expected,start_date,stop_date_original,stop_date_extended', 'date', 'format' => 'Y-m-d', 'allowEmpty' => true),
```

When I have a form, and I submit an empty value on say stop_date_extended, it is not set to NULL rather an empty string..

What am I doing wrong?
Surely there must be an easy work-around as not using the date validator works peachy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii Default Validator class handles the empty values like this :

/framework/validators/CDefaultValueValidator.php

```
protected function validateAttribute($object,$attribute)
{
    if(!$this->setOnEmpty)
        $object->$attribute=$this->value;
    else
    {
        $value=$object->$attribute;
        if($value===null || $value==='')
            $object->$attribute=$this->value;
    }
}
```

Given the function above your only issue could be that the value[i.e $value] posting by form could be not empty string probably `it might have spaces`. Probably you could try trim() the values before assigning them to model attributes. Or extend the default value validator e.g

```
class CMyDefaultValueValidator extends CDefaultValueValidator
{       
    protected function validateAttribute($object,$attribute)
    {
        if(!$this->setOnEmpty)
            $object->$attribute=$this->value;
        else
        {
            $value=trim($object->$attribute);
            if($value===null || $value==='')
                $object->$attribute=$this->value;
        }
    }
}
```

just note the line : **$value=trim($object->$attribute);**

Although,I haven't tested above code, I do not know if this is could be done some better way,

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert null for empty strings, you can do it in your model, after validation:

```
public function afterValidate()
{
    if(empty(trim($this->yourField))) // put whatever logic that you need
        $this->yourField = null;

    return parent::afterValidation();
}
```